# How to insert image near text in wpf DataGrid c#

Tags: c#, wpf, svg, datagrid

I made a code that populate a DataGrid. All working good, but now I want add near the field "name" an image. The link of this image is grabbed by a database. The image is on svg format, for this I'm using the resource svg2xaml.

This line of code return the image:

```
DrawingImage logo = SvgReader.Load(new MemoryStream(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Logo_FC_Bayern_München.svg")));
```

I use this code for populating the DataGrid:

```
MainWindow.AppWindow.Squadre_DataGrid.Items.Add(new Teams.Club_Information
{
         name = reader["name"].ToString()
}
```

This is my xaml structure:

```
<DataGrid>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'name'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Codice" Width="*" />
...
```

Can someone explain me how to add this image through code?

**UPDATE - dynamic link:**

```
 DrawingImage logo = SvgReader.Load(new MemoryStream(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(reader["link"].ToString())));
```

reader contain the link. I want send this link to NameToImageConverter like a reference: `NameToImageConverter nm = new NameToImageConveter();` but it's impossible because is a control. So How can I do this?

Comment: Is Club_Information class your class or 3rd party?

Comment: club_information is a struct, allow me to get the content of the JSON previously deserialized. But this isn't a problem for you. The question is about the "logo" variable and the image download throught svg2xaml for put them inside the DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If do not want to add new column, you have to replace DataGridTextColumn with DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Codice" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=crestUrl, Converter={StaticResource NameToImageConverter}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Note that you will have to add converter to your window resources:

```
<local:NameToImageConverter x:Key ="NameToImageConverter" />
```

Where "local" is namespace of your converter. And converter itself:

```
public class NameToImageConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // here you can return DrawingImage based on value that represents name field of your structure
        // just for example the piece of your code:
        if (value is string && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
        {
            return SvgReader.Load(new MemoryStream(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(value as string)));
        }
        else
        {
            // if value is null or not of string type
            return yourDefaultImage;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: <local:NameToImageConverter x:Name="NameToImageConverter" />, in particular the name "NameToImageConverter" doesn't exists into the project, but I've add it.

Comment: Of course it does not exist, that's why I gave you the code of this class

Comment: I put the class inside a folder called "GUI" and I've the same problem. Could you explain better?

Comment: I do not understand what exactly is wrong. I do not know your project structure, so I cannot say the exact value of "local" variable. Do you know about xmlns and namespace importing in xaml? If no, please view https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514546(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @HaroldFinch, In my case, class NameToImageConverter has namespace "Test31435155". So, "local" will be declared as "xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test31435155". If your class would be in another assembly, you will have to write it like that: "xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test31435155;assembly=AssemblyName"

Comment: Okay I've done. A little question, my link is dynamic so I need to pass the link like a parameter. How can I do? Because I can't create a reference of the class NameToImageConverter in the class that I want to send the link. See my update, please.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your link depends on name property, right? When WPF processor calls Convert method of NameToImageConverter class, it passes "name" variable as "object value". So, you can get it in Convert method as (string)value. You do not have to create an instance of NameToImageConverter, because WPF does it for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83403/discussion-between-harold-finch-and-vmaleev).